# How to iterate through and store various images that live in various folders under a root directory in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have 5 folders `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5` and I have several images in each folder.

What I am trying to do is make a dictionary object that holds all images based on their `key` (which is the folder name) and their `value` (which is the file names living under that specific folder).

The way I have written this is using `os.walk()`:

```
import os

dict_object = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for file_name in files:
        for dir_name in dirs:
            dict_object[dir_name] = [file_name]
```

But the output is not quite what I am after as it does not list the file names (`values`) under the appropriate folder names (`keys`):

```
dict_object

{'.DS_Store': [],
 'f1': ['.DS_Store'],
 '.ipynb_checkpoints': ['.DS_Store'],
 'f2': ['.DS_Store'],
 'f3': ['.DS_Store'],
 'f4': ['.DS_Store'],
 'f5': ['.DS_Store'],
 '.': ['.DS_Store']}
```

And I also do not want to include `'.DS_Store': []` and `'.': ['.DS_Store']` in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing this:

```
# Define various folders
folders = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"]
paths = []
file_paths = {}

# Put all paths together
for folder in range(len(folders)):
    paths.append('parentfolder/'+folders[folder]+'/')

    temp_file_paths = [os.path.join(paths[folder], f) for f in os.listdir(paths[folder])]

    if paths[folder] + '.DS_Store' in temp_file_paths:
        temp_file_paths.remove(paths[folder] + '.DS_Store')
    file_paths[folders[folder]] = temp_file_paths
```

`.DS_Store`: While it appears to be a useless addition to a folder, a `.DS_Store` file (the “DS” stands for “Desktop Services”) is important in helping Mac work out how to display folders when you open them. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store)

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish the wanted result with a simple recursive function.
For unwanted files, you can either filter the dictionary after the function invocation or change the if statement.

```
def recursive_read(path=".", dict_result={}):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
        if (root == '.'):
            continue
        if (root in dict_result):
            dict_result[root].append(files)
        else:
            dict_result[root] = files

        for dir in dirs:
            recursive_read(os.path.join(root, dir))
    return dict_result
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this but I have tried this before. This still does not solve my problem as the `key` in the dictionary is not just the file name, but the full path. Also, it does not get rid of the `'.DS_Store': []` and `'.': ['.DS_Store']` in the dictionary.

Comment: regarding unwanted files as I mentioned previously, you can filter the result. And also for the keys, you can format them accordingly.